# How to load JQuery from the own server, when it is not avaiable from the original source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig, assets

I'm trying to load JQuery from `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js`:

```
<script src="{{ asset('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

If the file is received, then get it. If not, get the file from the own server:

```
<script><window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="{{ asset("../app/Resources/public/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js") }}"><\/script>')</script>
```

but it gives me a syntax error. I've tried to scape the quotes but doesn't work:

```
<script><window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="{{ asset(\"../app/Resources/public/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js\") }}"><\/script>')</script>
```

It gives me again a syntax error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally achieved doing:

```
<script>
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
document.write('{% javascripts "../app/Resources/public/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" %} <script src="{{ asset_url }}"><\/script> {% endjavascripts %}');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can check it with this piece of code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js'     type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
```

You can find the full article with this piece of code here: [Jquery CDN fallback](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<script>
//try to Include from google here

if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
//if not included local source
}
</script>
```